# How to increment specific variable in 'for' loop?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have 567 arrays, each one with a specific length. I need to check each element of those 567 arrays, one by one, and depending on the element found, I need to increment a **specific** variable.

There are 100 counters created separetely, all started with 0, named counter_0, counter_1..., counter_99.

When I check each value of each array, I need to increment the counter corresponding to the array value, what means that if I found at position 1 of array 1 the value **90**, I must increment counter_90. The length of the 567 arrays varies, but all the values cointained are from 0 to 99...

How could I do this whole operation in `for` loops, referring to the variables?

I've tried:

```
for i in range(567):
    #this is a way of refer to array_i:
    for j in range(len('array_{}'.format(i))):
         #check each position of this array
            #if position checked has value = 10, increment counter_10
            #if position checked has value = 22, increment counter_22
               ...
```

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Start by using either a dictionary or an array to hold your counters.

Comment: I didn't think about that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to have a list of 100 numbers,

```
counters = [0] * 100
```

and store the index in your dictionary:

```
update = { 10: 10, 22 : 22 }
```

Then you can say

```
counters[update[checked_value]]+=1
```